# Computed property based on DOM, to update *after* render

Tags: vuejs2

What is the recommended way to have a computed property react to DOM property changes?

My scenario is this:
I have a computed property that is based on values found in DOM (e.g element width).
The DOM property changes as a result of the view update.
Now the computed property doesn't update as a result of DOM change.

I have made a codepen with a [simplified example](https://codepen.io/undefinederror/pen/YQxJrd?editors=1011) to illustrate the issue. In the example there I am forcing the computed property to update using a 'dummy' property that changes in the 'updated' hook.

```
updated(){
  console.log('updated')
  this.dummy= this.dummy * -1
},
computed:{
  width(){
    console.log('computed')
    const w = (this.$refs.square || {}).clientWidth
    return w + this.dummy * 0
  }
}
```

I do understand that if a property updates reacting to DOM changes, and DOM updates reacting to property changes, well, there would be no end to it.

So, is there any clean way to keep the two sync'd?

Thank you

Comment: You want to return the computed property to the value typed in the input box? atleast for me your question is not clear. :-|

Comment: the computed property is based on this.$refs.square.clientWidth. I'd like that property to react to a change of this.$refs.square.clientWidth, which doesn't happen. In my example in codepen, try typing "123456", you'll see this pattern ("i' for input value, "w" for current width): i:'1' => w:'', i:'12' => w:'1', i:'123' => w:'12', i:'1234' => w:'123', so on and so forth. w is always one update behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally rely on DOM properties; you would normally let the DOM be completely determined by data. That way you wouldn't have this issue.

That said, *at the cost of an additional render*, you could keep your properties in sync by using `$nextTick`.

```
data:{
  size:20,
  width: 20
},
methods:{
  onInput(e){
    this.size =e.target.value
    this.$nextTick(() => this.width = (this.$refs.square || {}).clientWidth)
  }
}
```

And just eliminate your computed entirely.

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yXzbzJ?editors=1011).

Comment: thanks @Best Evans. I can still use computed if ```this.width``` is used by it. Unfortunately I have to rely on DOM properties. I need to read the height of svg text deformed by a textpath. I find it crazy to try and work out what the height will be, when I have the property easily accessible from native DOM api.